# Field properties ShowInEditForm not saved

Tags: development, column

I have a `listadded EventReceiver` with the following code:

```
 public override void ListAdded(SPListEventProperties properties)
 {
    SPWeb web = properties.Web;
    bool safeUpdates = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    SPList list = properties.List;

    SPField VanField  = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("MyFieldName");
    VanField.ShowInEditForm = false;
    VanField.ShowInNewForm = false;
    VanField.Update(true);
    list.Update(true);
    web.Update();

    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = safeUpdates;
    base.ListAdded(properties);
}
```

The problem I have is that the `ShowInEditForm`  and `ShowInNewForm` not saved to the fields.

The event is a synchronous event. The field is an Taxonomy field, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that your EventReceiver is called after the list creation? Did you try to put a breakpoint in the method and debug it?

Comment: Yes i'm sure. It's running the code

Comment: I would try making this Added event synchronous. This way it will run 100% AFTER the list has been committed to the database.

Comment: It's already synchronous

Comment: ListAdded is not synchrous. ListAdding is.

Comment: Do you have several content types on the list?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this line :

```
VanField.PushChangesToLists = true;
```